Rocky Linux 9.4 constant crashes with new GPU
I do 3d art and was excited to get a new GPU, 7900XT. Week Before getting it, my grub corrupted because I resized my lvm partitions and moved them around, so now I have to manually boot through grub>.
After installing the new GPU, my system has become very unstable.
Here are some observations I made(all of these apply to both Wayland and X11 KDE plasma):

if I boot and log into either Wayland or X11, and don't move my mouse, the mouse will freeze within 3 minutes, then screen turns black, and my system will reboot on it's own.
if I boot and log, then asap open a browser and start a YouTube video, I know the system won't hang as long as the video is playing.(??) If I pause it, the system might or might not hang and reboot. It's a gamble. If it doesn't hang a few mins after pausing, then I can go for hours without issue.
Journalctl reports nothing that could explain these crashes.
the pc works fine if I stay in ctrl-alt-f3 or other (I think it's called tty?) any nongraphical session is stable.

I tried the following:

updating motherboard bios
updating amd drivers manually (amdgpu_install from their proprietary repo)
changing session types (x11)

My current boot process:

Fail at bios cause my usb keyboard fails to detect.
Reboot
Get to GRUB cli cause my grub/efi broke and I can't fix it for a week now, so I have to manualy type:
3.1. set root=(hd0,gpt4)
3.2. linux /vmlinuz-5....7..... root=/dev/mapper/rl-root
3.3. initrd /initramfs-5...7....
3.4. boot
Log into Linux, wait 1 min for it to crash.
4.1. MAYBE if I immediately start browser and yt video on boot, the system seems to crash way less likely on first/second boot?!
Redo everything above except 4, cause now there's a 50/50 chance it will stay working.
Repeat five, chances it stays stable increase every reboot
Profit (10min later?)

From what I saw online, Wayland and kernel weren't saying nicely with the 7900xt till recently, so the only solution I can think of is to compile a custom kernel with latest version and use that (then what's the point of using rhel9...) or maybe only latest Wayland (GCC is outdated on rhel9, so I can't.)
Please give me some ideas how to fix it. I really don't want to reinstall. It would take me a week to get all the programs I need set up again, and many of them don't work on other distros(davinci resolve only works on rhel7-9, even provide a custom distro just for their program...)
inxi:
djkato@djkato-vfx ~> inxi -I -G
Graphics:
  Device-1: AMD Navi 31 [Radeon RX 7900 XT/7900 XTX/7900 GRE/7900M]
    driver: amdgpu v: 6.8.5
  Device-2: AMD Raphael driver: amdgpu v: 6.8.5
  Display: wayland server: X.org v: 1.20.11 with: Xwayland v: 22.1.9
    compositor: kwin_wayland driver: X: loaded: amdgpu unloaded: modesetting
    dri: radeonsi gpu: amdgpu,amdgpu resolution: 1: 3072x1728 2: 2560x1440
  API: EGL v: 1.5 drivers: kms_swrast,radeonsi,swrast
    platforms: gbm,wayland,x11,surfaceless,device
  API: OpenGL v: 4.6 vendor: amd mesa v: 24.2.0-devel renderer: Radeon RX
    7900 XT (radeonsi navi31 LLVM 18.1.7 DRM 3.58
    5.14.0-427.37.1.el9_4.x86_64)
  API: Vulkan v: 1.3.268 drivers: radv,llvmpipe surfaces: xcb,xlib,wayland
Info:
  Memory: total: 32 GiB note: est. available: 30.5 GiB used: 3.62 GiB (11.9%)
  Processes: 366 Uptime: 26m Shell: fish inxi: 3.3.33


Trying again :) Do you have kdump enabled? If so is there any diagnostic data in /var/crash? Especially vmcore-dmesg.txt may be helpful.
